# How to configure failover in edgerouter x 5 ports?

Tags: ubiquiti-edgerouter

I have connected to my edgerouter x 5 ports, 2 WAN (WAN1 to eth0 and WAN2 to eth1 in failover)

Problem: WAN1 has 10 Mbps and WAN2 Failover 8 Mbps. When WAN1 drops, but not enough (example: 1 or 0.5 Mpbs), WAN2 failover does not enter.

What I want is that when WAN1 drops to XX Mbps, WAN2 goes into operation in failover mode and returns to WAN1 when it exceeds XX Mbps, in a recovery time of XX minutes

Where XX are values that I determine manually

**My edgerouter x:**

[image]

[image]

I did not find the information in the ubiquiti user manuals for this router [HERE](https://manuals.plus/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Ubnt-Ubiquiti-EdgeRouter-X-ER-X-User-Manual.pdf), [HERE](https://dl.ubnt.com/guides/edgemax/EdgeOS_UG.pdf) or [HERE](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/205145990-EdgeRouter-WAN-Load-Balancing)

I appreciate the help.

PS: I apologize if this is not the right forum to ask this question. I searched on stackexchange but didn't find any hardware to post this question

Comment: *What* parameter do you want to trigger on? When available bandwidth is under 2Mb/s? How can you know if available BW is <2Mb/s?

Comment: The question describes the scenario. What I want to activate the failover when I want, according to my parameters and not when the router decides.

Comment: How do you determine the available bandwidth?

Comment: I suppose that it will be necessary to take them from the RX/TX (although these values do not represent reality, but it is close). But I really wouldn't know

Comment: You can't do that. You don't know why you have low speed. It can be a video feed that just happens to consume 400Kb/s, or it can be a download that is slow. The problem is simply that the router has ***no way of knowing*** the parameter you want to act upon. This is not a trivial problem; it's fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as Ethernet running at 2Mbps. If you have some other means of getting a bandwidth report reliably (e.g. DSL or 3G modem status page) you can incorporate this check in a bash script, save it somewhere in `/config/scripts` so it will survive firmware upgrades and then call it in your load-balance stanzas like in the example below.

In this example WAN2 is on `eth2` and is a backup, while WAN1 is on `eth1` and its the primary link. You would also need to create routing tables 10 and 20 with the appropriate defaults in each and reference them in firewall modify rules:

```
load-balance {
group WAN2 {
    exclude-local-dns disable
    flush-on-active disable
    gateway-update-interval 20
    interface eth1 {
        failover-only
        route {
            table 10
        }
        route-test {
            initial-delay 180
            interval 60
            type {
                script /config/scripts/pinger
            }
        }
    }
    interface eth2 {
        route {
            table 20
        }
        route-test {
            initial-delay 180
            interval 60
            type {
                script /config/scripts/pinger
            }
        }
    }
    lb-local disable
    lb-local-metric-change disable
}
group WAN1 {
    exclude-local-dns disable
    flush-on-active disable
    gateway-update-interval 20
    interface eth1 {
        route {
            table 10
        }
        route-test {
            initial-delay 180
            interval 60
            type {
                script /config/scripts/pinger
            }
        }
    }
    interface eth2 {
        failover-only
        route {
            table 20
        }
        route-test {
            initial-delay 180
            interval 60
            type {
                script /config/scripts/pinger
            }
        }
    }
    lb-local disable
    lb-local-metric-change disable
}
}
```

The script is called with three parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash
targets=(
    '192.168.10.1'
    '192.168.20.1'
    '192.168.30.1' )
if [ $# != 3 ]
then
  echo "Usages: $0 <group> <intf> <status>"
  exit 1
fi

group=$1
intf=$2
status=$3

for host in "${targets[@]}"
do
  /bin/ping -n -c 1 -W 1 -w1 -I $intf $host
  if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
      exit 0
  fi
done

# fail

exit 1
```

This script uses ping via interface provided by EdgeOS upon the script startup to check availability of three uplink hosts and returns `0` (ok) if at least one of them responds and `1` (failure) when no hosts respond.

You could use the same approach to implement some logic so that when the `$intf` has a good status according to your checks, return `0` with `exit 0`, otherwise return `1` with `exit 1`.

Comment: So, according to your answer, the "Trigger Level" and "Recovery Time" failover options do not exist in the Edgarouter-5-ports configuration.

Comment: There's no such thing in EdgeOs in general, as far as I'm aware. Built-in functionality for load balancing is `route-test type ping` with success and failure counters triggering failure and recovery. But you can alter this with `route-test type script` as I described in my answer and implement your own logic in this script.

Comment: I think you should explain how your script works and why you set those values

Comment: I have included a complete script we use here to monitor dual-wan networks on EdgeOS together with a brief explanation of the logic behind it.